# How do I run PigUnit on the command line

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

It isn't clear to me how to run PigUnit on the command line.  I've seen some documentation that mentions some interaction with JUnit, but I don't have much experience with it.

So, if I have pigunit.jar, junit.jar and my PigUnitTests.jar in the same folder, how do I run PigUnit on the command line?

Using pig-0.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to run jUnit, so assuming your jars are in the current directory, use:

```
java -cp ./pigunit.jar:./junit.jar:./PigUnitTests.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore <Your.Test.ClassName>
```

Comment: Thanks @highlycaffeinated!  And, what do I change in they're not in the same directory?

Comment: If they're not all in the same directory, change your classpath to include all the directories and all the jars: java -cp .:<path/to/jar2>:<path/to/jar3>